# List tables queried by Power BI in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I usually use SCHEMA_METADATA to track what is happening in my companies dataset. We use Power BI's connector to update datasets based on our Bigquery Tables, once a day.
If I refresh my reports manually in my Power BI Desktop datasets, I can find all queries done by Power BI with the next query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE date(creation_time)=CURRENT_DATE()
ORDER BY creation_time DESC
```

For some reason, If I refresh the reports on Power BI interface, I don't see these queries. I need to track all tables refreshed, but I would have to manually refresh each dataset in order to achieve this.

Do you have any hint on what may be happening?

I tried refreshing in all possible ways in Power BI website.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing a report in Power BI portal does not perform a dataset refresh, it merely does a visuals refresh.

You will need to trigger a Dataset refresh in the portal.